# Why static binding works differently for class and function?

Tags: python, class, scope, static-binding

In python (tested on 2.7.6) all variables are
statically bound to a scope at compile time. This process is well
described in http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0227/ and
http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/executionmodel.html

It is explicitly stated that "If a name binding operation occurs
anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name within the block
are treated as references to the current block."

A function is a code block so the following code with fail because `x`
is assigned after its use (so at compile time it is defined local
because it is assigned somewhere in the function, but at execution
time, it is used before being bound).

```
x = 1
def f():
    print x 
    x = 2
    print x

>>> f()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#46>", line 1, in <module>
    f()
  File "<pyshell#45>", line 2, in f
    print x
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

A class is also a code block, so we should observe exactly the
same behavior. But this is not what I observe.
Look at this example:

```
x = 1
class C():
    y = x + 10
    x = 2
    def __init__(self):
        print C.y

>>> C.x
2
>>> C.y
11      
>>> C()
11
<__main__.C instance at 0x00000000027CC9C8>
```

As the class definition is a code block, any assignment within this
block should make the variable local. So `x` should be local to the
class `C`, so `y = x + 10` should result in an `UnboundLocalError`. 
Why there is not such error?

Comment: This thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810426/differences-between-class-block-and-function-block-in-python refers to the same issue, but no strong explanation is given. PEP-0227 and python 2.7 execution model do not make any difference between of function block or a class block

Comment: This is a common scoping issue. Notice the difference in the namespaces between the following: `<function f at 0x1092a80c8>` and `<class __main__.C at 0x1092946d0>`. The difference is the `__main__` namespace.

Comment: Also, this is very closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12810426/differences-between-class-block-and-function-block-in-python

Comment: @VooDooNOFX I still don't get your explanation. A class is a code  block and a variable assigned anywhere in a code block is local. This is not what I observe. It looks like there is a static binding for functions only, but I do not find any reference to this behavior in the Python documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - it seems that the documentation is rather misleading.  A class definition doesn't actually work quite the same as other normal blocks:

```
global_one = 0

class A(object):
    x = global_one + 10
    global_one = 100
    y = global_one + 20
    del global_one
    z = global_one + 30

a = A()
print a.x, a.y, a.z, global_one
```

results in: `10, 120, 30, 0`

if you try the same thing with a function, you get an `UnboundLocalError` on your first access of `global_one`.

The reason for this is that class definitions as normal have access to the parent scope, however, all name assignments do NOT modify a local scope, but in fact are captured into the class's data attributes dictionary.  There are hints about this in the documentation, but it's certainly not obvious.