# How to reference a static attribute from within a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, constructor

I have the following python snippet:

```
class myClass:
    myVar = 'a'

    def __init__(self):
        self.myOtherVar = 'b'
        myVar = 'c'  # Gets assigned but only as a local variable.

    print myVar            # prints 'a' !
    print self.myOtherVar  # says 'self' not found
```

My question is this;
What's the proper way to print the contents of `myVar` from within `myClass` and/or re-assign them from `init`?

Comment: duplicate of [Static class variables in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: For me it prints `'a'` for `print myVar`.

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct?

Comment: There is nothing special about `self`; it is just the conventional name for the the first argument to a method, which automatically gets assigned to the instance being called. Outside of methods, you can access class-level attributes directly.

Comment: What you describe is not true. That code prints `a` and then an error since `self` doesn't exist. But `myVar` is **not** `None` and does *not* raise an error. Also, if the line with `myVar` raises an error then how you know that the following line raises an error too, since it wont be executed?

Comment: @Bakuriu You are corrent. My bad. `myVar` prints out correctly. The real problem is that I can't access it from `myClass` init. And if I do, I will have simply created a new -local- one.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yes identation is correct. Please see updated answer.

Comment: @bereal Please see updated answer. `myVar` simply can't be accessed from within `__init__`.

Comment: @Konos5 you have to use `myClass.myVar` inside `__init__`.

Comment: @Konos5 The syntax for accessing class's static variable is as in the thread I posted above. `myClass.myVar` in this case. It doesn't matter from where you do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you don't understand how the scoping of class declarations work. A class declaration is **executed** in its own scope. After the execution is completed a new class object is created and the obtained scope is attached to the class as its `__dict__`.

**Note**: the class scope is *not* searched from within the methods scopes! This means that you have to reference class attributes as `MyClass.attribute` when *inside* a method definition.

For example:

```
class MyClass:
    var = 1

    # we are executing this code as a single block
    # so you must reference the variable as is usual
    print(var)

    # default values are *not* inside the definition.
    # they are evaluated in the outer scope, so use plain "var" here
    def method(self, a_default=var):
        print(a_default)

    def other_method(self):

        # inside methods you are in a different scope
        print(MyClass.var)

        # equivalent *if* no "var" instance attributes exists
        print(self.var)
```

Note: since the class doesn't still exist when executing its declaration you *cannot* refer to `MyClass` at the "top level" of `MyClass` declaration:

```
class MyClass:
    var = 1
    print(MyClass.var)   # error: MyClass still doesn't exist.
```

---

A side effect of this, is that the following code:

```
class MyClass:
    x = 1
    results = list(i+x for i in range(10))
```

Produces:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f1d4417b2e52> in <module>()
----> 1 class MyClass:
      2     x = 1
      3     results = list(i+x for i in range(10))
      4 

<ipython-input-6-f1d4417b2e52> in MyClass()
      1 class MyClass:
      2     x = 1
----> 3     results = list(i+x for i in range(10))
      4 

<ipython-input-6-f1d4417b2e52> in <genexpr>(.0)
      1 class MyClass:
      2     x = 1
----> 3     results = list(i+x for i in range(10))
      4 

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Because generator expressions (and list-comprehensions in python3) are, in fact, considered functions with their own scope. Since the class scope isn't searched from inner function scopes the `x` cannot be found.

You can word around this using a function definition and default values:

```
class MyClass:
    x = 1
    def _make_results(x=x):
        return list(i+x for i in range(10))
    results = _make_results()
    del _make_results    # otherwise it would be added as a method.
    # or:
    results = (lambda x=x: list(i+x for i in range(10)))()
```

This isn't usually a problem since class definitions rarely contain anything other than method definitions and a few constants.

---

There are already a few questions on SO about class scopes:

- [The scope of names defined in class block doesn't extend to the methods' blocks. Why is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505979/the-scope-of-names-defined-in-class-block-doesnt-extend-to-the-methods-blocks)
- [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules/292502#292502)
- [Nested classes' scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/python-nested-classes-scope)
- [Variable scopes in python classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5690888/variable-scopes-in-python-classes)
- [Why static binding works differently for class and function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148256/why-static-binding-works-differently-for-class-and-function)

Comment: An exemplary answer by all means. However I need one last clarification; You said that *I cannot refer to MyClass at the "top level" of MyClass declaration* but instead I can do it from within one of its method declarations. This simply begs the question: When exactly is a **class** considered alive so that I can start refering to it? And I iterate - not the instance but the class.

Comment: As soon as the `class` block ends. You can use it it in methods, because a function's body is only evaluated once you call it. Which is after the class definition's parsed and executed.

Comment: @Konos5 A class is "alive" after its body is evaluated. The evaluation of a method definition means that its code is *compiled*. So inside a method there is no problem referring to `MyClass` because, since the method isn't executed, the reference will be only evaluated after the class was completely created. As far as the method is concerned `MyClass` is just a global variable. In fact you can access the class also as `self.__class__` without referencing `MyClass`. However `self.__class__` may not be `MyClass` if you create some subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

`self.var` will:

1. give `var` in `self.__dict__` if present
2. give `var` in `self.__class__.__dict__` if present
3. `AttributeError`

So use this or `self.__class__.var` if you want to access the static variable **minding inheritance**. If you extend `myClass`, the children instances will access the static variable in the child class.

If you want to access the static variable in `myClass` even when called from descendants, use `myClass.var`.

As for **reassigning** them, this must be done explicitly on the class object, or the assignment will just target the instance.

Comment: No. From within myClass I can't do `print myClass.var`. Python spits out an error saying the `myClass` is not defined.

Comment: @Konos5 You can't `print` within a class, but not within its method. Could just please read the duplicate I've given link to? It contains everything there is to know on static variables in Python.

Comment: @BartoszKP I'm looking at it as we speak. However I still can't seem to find a clear way of reassigning the static variavle `myVar` from within `myClass`'s `__init__` method...

Comment: @Konos5 It's the same syntax as everywhere else in that thread: `myClass.myVar`. It doesn't matter from where you do it. It's a variable inside that class, `.` always means reaching inside of something.

Answer (score -4):

```
class myClass:
    myVar = 'a'

    def __init__(self):
        self.myOtherVar = 'b'

    print myVar  # -> 'a'

    class EmptyClass: pass
    s = EmptyClass()
    __init__(s)

    myVar = s.myOtherVar
    print myVar  # -> 'b'

print myClass.myVar  # -> 'b'
```

Comment: Care to explain what exactly did you do here? I am looking for the functionality you demostrate but in a more "clean" way. Also at some point you wrote `__init__(s)`... which class that __init__ refers to?

Comment: We have to call `myClass.__init__` with some instance to get `'b'`. So I created an empty class called `EmptyClass` then I used instance of `EmptyClass` to call `myClass.__init__` by `__init__(s)` so `__init__` refers to `myClass`